# Laravel 5: Pagination links on raw query does not work

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

I have a raw query which is working properly but i am trying to paginate it as below

```
$query_result = DB::select($query);
$query_result = new Paginator($query_result, 5, 1);
return view('pages.printout', compact('query_result'));
```

And in blade

```
{!! str_replace('/?', '?', $query_result->render()) !!}
```

First page comes up okay, it paginates first 5 records but when i click to pagination links no change happens. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your error log?

Comment: seems like i dont get any errors, dunno what is wrong @whoacowboy

Comment: Just realized that links does not work because anytime i click to the links the query that i create dynamically backs to its initial value since page is refreshing. Therefore data is not shown properly. Any suggestions about how can i run the same query after i click to links ?

Comment: if you load the page with `?page=2` do you get the expected for page 2?.

Comment: @whoacowboy yes sorta, but since page got refreshed dynamically created query back to its initial value so i can not get some part of the expected data.

Comment: Can you post your $query? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way

```
$query_result = DB::select($query)->paginate(5);
return view('pages.printout', compact('query_result'));
```